# How to echo a variable following a string in bash?

Tags: bash, output, stderr, io-redirection, openssh

I need to print the output of the "ssh -V" command inbetween some xml nodes. I want it to look like

```
<sshname>OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017</sshname>
```

but the code below is printing the command's output before the nodes.

```
sshname=$(ssh -V)
echo "<sshname> $sshname</sshname>"
```

Result:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
<sshname> </sshname>
```

Why is that happening? and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect ssh's stderr (2) to stdout (1), too:

```
sshname=$(ssh -V 2>&1)
```

---

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams